# GM_xmlhttprequest pyload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

I'm trying to authenticate through PyLoad's API using tampermonkey/greasemonkey but the cookie isn't sent neither in the response nor in the headers. 
It succeed to login but the answer is different from that of firefox console (cookie is missing).

**Greasemonkey :** 
*responseText:*   true 
*responseHeader:* Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate 
--------------- Content-Length: 4 
--------------- Content-Type: application/json 
--------------- Date: Sun, 11 Feb 2018 20:39:10 GMT 
--------------- Server: CherryPy/3.1.2 WSGI Server

**firefox :** 
*response:* 67fc662d6[...]758b2f94ffd2 
*header:*   Cache-Control no-cache, must-revalidate 
--------- Content-Length 34 
--------- Content-Type application/json 
--------- Date Sun, 11 Feb 2018 19:59:11 GMT 
--------- Server CherryPy/3.1.2 WSGI Server 
--------- Set-cookie beaker.session.id=67fc662d6…Jan-2038 04:14:07 GMT; Path=/

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve There is no *example* for us to review or to help understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is only present in the first request and won't be resent for days.
A session is created so there is no need to re-use the cookie in the following requests.